# Does taking a reference to an object via two different base classes violate strict aliasing rule?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, strict-aliasing

I have three pure virtual classes, let's call them `ServiceA`, `ServiceB` and `ServiceC`.

The concrete implementation provides all three services using multiple inheritance:

```cpp
class Concrete : public ServiceA, public ServiceB, public ServiceC
{
    //...
};
```

It is possible that the services could also be provided by separate concrete classes (single inheritance), so to make use of the services, I'm thinking to write a class like so:

```cpp
class Consumer
{
public:
    Consumer(const ServiceA& svcA, const ServiceB& svcB);
};
```

If instantiate my class as shown below, will that be a violation of the strict aliasing rule?

```cpp
Concrete multiService;
Consumer consumer(multiService, multiService);
```

Comment: I don't get how this have to do with strict aliasing rule.

Comment: strict aliasing is about treating something as something it isn't.  All derived classes have an  `is-a` relationship with their base classes so you are allowed to take references to the bases. I don't see any glaring issues but we need an [mre] of the usage to know for sure.

Comment: The two references don't even have the same address: https://godbolt.org/z/KKh9bjz5T

Comment: C++17 standard 8.2.1 "If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined", and then "a type that is a base class type of the dynamic type of the object". So of course, you are good to go. Otherwise c++ polymorphism wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. The rule is for incompatible types, which doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: @Armandas the types of the references are incompatible, but their addresses are different

Comment: @TheDreamsWind Thanks. I meant to say that the reference type and the object are compatible types.

Comment: Nitpick: there is no such thing as "pure virtual classes", only abstract classes (or ABC = abstract base classes), that is, classes with pure virtual functions, either declared or inherited.

Comment: that is not true, strict aliasing simply is not concerned by custom types...it only affects scalars as that what definitions of "access" means ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If instantiate my class as shown below, will that be a violation of the strict aliasing rule?

Strict aliasing rule doesn't break because `svcA` and `svcB` do not refer to the same address in the memory. When you refer to base classes, you actually refer to *subobjects* of the complete class `Consumer`, where each has its own offset (which might be more than zero), and thus different addresses even for the same instance of `Consumer`.

Comment: That's a good point. I learnt something new. Thanks!